# Kotlin, CheckBox и Button

Tags: kotlin, checkbox, if

Есть чекбокс и кнопка, при включенном чекбоксе должен сменяться активити, при отключенном вылетать тост. Выдается ошибка:

> Expecting member declaration

В строках `if` и `else`. Просьба подсказать, что не так, т.к. я явно чего-то не понимаю.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val checkBox = findViewById (R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox
    }
            if (checkBox.isChecked)
                fun gotoActivityTwo(view: View) {
                    val gotoActivityTwo = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
                    startActivity(gotoActivityTwo)
                }
            else
                fun showToast(view: View) {
                    val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                            "Так не пойдет, хитрюга :)",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                    toast.show()
                }
}
```

Comment: Почему у Вас if else вне функции? Вам следует на checkbox навесить listener, типо onCheck... Не помню точно, и уже в реализации необходимого метода запихнуть ваш if else

Answer (score 1):

`Expecting member declaration` означает, что на этой строчке компилятор ожидает увидеть объявление переменной или функции (одним словом — это instance members). Конструкция `if` на этом месте стоять не может, произвольный код можно писать только внутри методов или в init-блоке:

```
class Foo {

    init {
        // код в блоке init
    }

    fun bar() {
        // код в методе bar
    }

    // в этом месте if-else писать нельзя, только внутри init или bar

}
```